# Seed Data Syntax Error

Tags: ruby, syntax

I'm super new to rails and coding,

I have my seed.rb file and the first line is

```
Food.create! ( name: "Avocado")
```

When I try to rake db:seed, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/meganryll/Desktop/foodninja/db/seeds.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting ')'
Food.create! ( name: "Avocado")
```

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with that syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby does not like spaces between the method name and the argument parentheses.

```
Food.create!( name: "Avocado")
```